# Hexproof and the stack

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a 1/1 [Kitesail Scout](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKitesail%20Scout%5d) and use a +1/+1 pump spell to make it a 2/2. My opponent casts a [Fiery Temper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFiery%20Temper%5d) to deal 3 damage to it. I respond with [Blossoming Defense](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlossoming%20Defense%5d) for +2/+2 and Hexproof, he responds with [Murder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMurder%5d).

Does the Kitesail Scout die?

I know the last in first out stack rule, but didn't my Kitesail have Hexproof, so therefore his Murder could not be cast as the Kitesail was no longer a legal target?

Comment: You can link cards using the `[mtg:Cardname]` syntax. If you decide to explain what cards do instead or in addition, make sure you don't confuse their function - Fiery Temper does not do -3/-3, but deals 3 damage.

Comment: @TheThirdMan I've found `[mtg:cardname]` doesn't work well, every time I have used it it runs a search on gatherer, so it often pulls up multiple matches, murder for instance in this question has 11 matches. I still prefer direct links to the actual gatherer page for that reason.

Answer (score 10):

[With only a few exceptions](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5B%22when%20you%20cast%22%5D), spells only have an effect once they resolve.
Just like you can cast [Blossoming Defense](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlossoming%20Defense%5d) in response to their [Fiery Temper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFiery%20Temper%5d) to save your creature before it would be killed, your opponent can respond to your Blossoming Defense by casting [Murder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMurder%5d) to kill your creature before it's being protected.

**Your 2/2 [Kitesail Scout](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKitesail%20Scout%5d) will be destroyed by Murder. Blossoming Defense and Fiery Temper will be countered by the game rules for not having any legal targets when they would resolve**

> **608. Resolving Spells and Abilities**
>
> **608.2b.** If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. A target that’s no longer in the zone it was in when it was targeted is illegal. (...) The spell or ability is countered if all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal. (...)
>
> **608.2c.** The controller of the spell or ability follows its instructions in the order written. (...)

---

If instead your opponent allowed Blossoming Defense to resolve and didn't cast Murder in response to it, the Kitesail Scout would indeed be an illegal target for the spell and therefore couldn't be cast.

> **601. Casting Spells**
>
> **601.2.** To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. Casting a spell includes proposal of the spell (rules 601.2a–d) and (...). To cast a spell, a player follows the steps listed below, in order. (...) If, at any point during the casting of a spell, a player is unable to comply with any of the steps listed below, the casting of the spell is illegal; the game returns to the moment before the casting of that spell was proposed (see rule 720, “Handling Illegal Actions”).
>
> **601.2c.** The player announces his or her choice of an appropriate player, object, or zone for each target the spell requires. (...) The chosen players, objects, and/or zones each become a target of that spell. (...)

Comment: @Tony: If this or another answer sufficiently answered your question, consider marking it as the accepted answer instead of using comments. There's a [Help Center article about how to act when a question's been answered](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Your Blossoming Defense also uses the stack, so the creature does not have hexproof until it resolves.  So, I'm assuming your opponent cast Murder before your spell resolved, so it did not have hexproof at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You only get hexproof when the spell resolves, which means your creature will die before getting hexproof.

It depends on when it is cast. I'm guessing all were instants and abilities and cast as response to the last casting, without any of it resolving. So the order goes:

1. fiery temper goes on stack
2. blossoming defense goes on stack
3. murder goes on stack
4. murder resolves (kills creature)
5. blossoming defense does not resolve (no target, so it is countered)
6. fiery temper does not resolve (no target, so it is countered)

Comment: In your example, Blossoming Defense and Fiery Temper won't resolve. Instead, they will be countered by the game rules for having no legal targets.

Comment: I think resolves just means "is processed". It is indeed countered by the lack of target during the resolution. Here is an example where the rules refer to one such spell being countered, as resolving: “If the creature isn’t a legal target during the resolution of Sorin’s Thirst (..), then Sorin’s Thirst is countered." Notice they say "resolution of Sorin's Thirst".

Comment: [608.2b](https://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Game+Rules#_ucRuleBookSelector__ucRuleBook_dlRules_ctl1082_lblRuleCode) mentions "If the spell or ability is not countered, it will resolve normally.", which is why I'm phrasing it that way, although the rules in general talk about a spell resolving until the point where it's countered... Either way, we're obviously talking about the same meaning, and "it won't resolve normally" is likely more accurate, if not as elegant :)

Comment: Yeah, we were reading the same section. I took that as "if it's countered it'll resolve differently" xD

Comment: @CyberClaw It's supposed to mean "if it's countered it will not resolve at all". Rule 701.5a is the explicit statement of that. The example you quoted with Sorin's Thirst is incorrectly worded, assuming the stuff you omitted from the middle doesn't change the context.

Comment: Like I said, we were reading the same section of the rulebook. If you want the full example it's right below 608.2b. "Example: Sorin's Thirst is a black instant that reads, "Sorin's Thirst deals 2 damage to target creature and you gain 2 life." If the creature isn't a legal target during the resolution of Sorin's Thirst (say, if the creature has gained protection from black or left the battlefield), then Sorin's Thirst is countered. Its controller doesn't gain any life."

Comment: Other examples that show they use resolve as meaning "is processed". -> "608.2j. If an instant spell, sorcery spell, or ability that can legally resolve leaves the stack once it starts to resolve, it will continue to resolve fully." Why would they say "resolve fully" if resolve implied being completed? Resolve means just that. "Dealing with it". Does it fizz due to illegal target? Well it's done anyway. It's resolved. The dictionary classifies resolve as "settle or find a solution to". I'm just applying the dictionary definition.

Comment: Ah, found the actual answer. I was wrong. On the glossary of the same rulebook above linked: "Resolve: When the spell or ability on top of the stack "resolves," its instructions are followed and it has its effect. "